# How to programmatically determine if an Active Directory trust is transitive in OpenLDAP?

Tags: active-directory, openldap, directoryservices

When using OpenLDAP, I can get the trustAttributes, trustType, and trustDirection attributes from the AD server.  However, it isn't clear from the documentation how to determine (in all cases) when a trust is transitive.  Can someone shed some light on this (or at least a pointer)?

Note that I am not using C# or any .NET calls.  I just need to see how to test the bits/values in the attributes to figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you're using the OpenLDAP *clients?*

Comment: I am using the OpenLDAP library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the ldap attribute `trustAttribute` in the ldap object `objectclass=trusteddomain` has the trust relationship. The link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223779 details what each bit means.

The following link may also be useful http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Active-Directory-2a9e15d2